# Footer Center Align while using Float

Tags: css, css-float, footer

I am using UL Li Elements to create a footer links like in the link http://mink7.com/projects/cmrc/home.html

I want to center align. all the elements of the footer.
Since i am using Float am not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: Where do you need to use float ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:inline` or `inline-block` and parent tag align text in center like `text-align:center`, may be it will help you..

Answer (score 1):

Used this once, dont really know if [this](http://www.markrushworth.com/css-center-unordered-list-ulli-based-menu/) is what you need

Comment: While the information at the target URL may answer the question, we prefer the answer to be *here on our site*, with the link provided as a further reference. Please include relevant information from your source here. [Read more at meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259)